# Mail is not send in wordpress blog by contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am making a WordPress blog and contact us form data trying to send the mail in my email but not send in the mail:

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide more information re your server setup - is this on a localhost server or online? Do you have mail/mx records setup on your domain if the website it hosted online?

Comment: This is on a live host server of GoDaddy server Linux Hosting. mail is active mail is sent and receive both

Comment: Do you receive emails from your wordpress blog for any other activity such as registering a new user/changing your password? Your mail settings could be incomplete server side  or your emails may be getting stuck in spam folder or even your domain/server IP might be blacklisted. I found Easy WP SMTP to be a good plugin for my emails - https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/